# I was there singing?

Tags: relative-clauses

Is this a relative clause when I say:

> I was there singing.

And

> I was there where I was singing.

are these sentences similar with each other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative clauses are described here -

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/clauses

The latter is a relative clause, the former is not.
Both are similar in terms of information content.

Without more context it's hard to give a concrete usage example, but if you are describing a situation/event/location where you were singing then "I was singing there" is a valid form.  I would not use the second form, and would write the first form as "I was there, singing."

Comment: Is it the same to say "I was there and I was singing?"

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.